# Transpose using CUDA : Inquiry on program in Blog

Tags: c++, matrix, cuda, transpose

I have given blog below link as an example for Matrix transpose, as below link it shows how to do transpose matrix using 3 methods, naive, Coalesced and Nobankconflict Coalesced

https://github.com/parallel-forall/code-samples/blob/master/series/cuda-cpp/transpose/transpose.cu

in Main() , when calling the kernel code,  all 3 methods call it in similar way, like below code part(taken from the main function-host )  :

```
cudaMemset(d_tdata, 0, mem_size);
// warmup
transposeNoBankConflicts << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> >(d_tdata, d_idata);
cudaEventRecord(startEvent, 0);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_REPS; i++)
    transposeNoBankConflicts << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> >(d_tdata, d_idata);
cudaEventRecord(stopEvent, 0);
cudaEventSynchronize(stopEvent);
cudaEventElapsedTime(&ms, startEvent, stopEvent);
cudaMemcpy(h_tdata, d_tdata, mem_size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

i even read the web with the explanation of the code, its a good reference for matrix transpose

http://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/efficient-matrix-transpose-cuda-cc/

but there is one part which was not explained :

why as you can see the Kernel is called twice :
1\ once for as comment says warm up 
2\ second under for loop up to 100 times (NUM_REPS) which is a #define value initialized to 100,

so why not call it once ? why two times and second 100 loops ?
even though ive tested by using only one of them, they both give valid output but the time is different,

hope my quesyion is clear and pls inform me if anything needs to be noted, thank you

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with matrix transpose: these are some of the basics for accurately timing blocks of code.

The first key point is that functions often run so quickly that you can't get precise estimates of their runtime from your timing functions: thus, the need to run the function many times in a loop so that you can get better precision.

(and you have to take care that you are actually timing what you want; sometimes optimizers are clever and the simplest thing you try won't actually be timing what you want; e.g. the optimizer might find a way to efficiently blend together the end and beginning of your code, or it might notice you're not using the output of the first 99 times through the loop so it won't bother running them. You're probably safe from this effect with `nvcc`, though, since it will almost surely compile the kernel into an opaque function call)

The second key point is that the first iteration will often be slower than later iterations for a number of reasons, some listed below. Thus, to get an accurate timing, you often don't want to include the first iteration in your timings.

- maybe your data is normally in cache, but it's not yet there for your first iteration, so the first time will get a lot of cache misses. (conversely, if your code is expected to run with data *not* in cache and being in cache already would affect the timings, you should do something to pollute the cache between iterations)
- on CPUs, the first time touching a region of memory will generate page faults, which can be really slow. I'm not sure if this effect shows up on GPUs
- underutilized compute units on GPUs may switch to a power saving mode. I'm not familiar with the details, but the point is that the first time through (or maybe the first several times through) the GPU might be underclocked, or many functional units might be turned off, and "warming up" the GPU will restore it to its full ability.

Comment: many thanks for your explanation it really cleared up my inquiries!!! , but : is there a reason on choosing 100 times to run to get an accurate time ? i mean is it like the best constant to use ? also as note im running on OS windows so wont be using the nvcc as compilation , one other note  : isnt increasing the sending between host and kernel not advantage as far as i know? i mean i was noted that we should decrease the communication between host and device right ? will if affect in this 100 iteration,

Comment: @user: Usually I choose the number of iterations to be as large as I can, without making the timing program long enough to make me impatient. I usually arrange for the test to be on the order of one second overall, but there's no real science behind that choice.